# Proof by induction, simplification step

Tags: induction

i have to prove (3/4)(5^(k+2) -1)

I have so far (after using inductive hypothesis etc): (3/4)(5^(K+1) -1) +3*5^(K+1)

I can't seen to find a useful common factor to simplify although i'm sure it would be 3*5^(k+1)

any help would be appreciated! Also, sorry about the styling i can't manage to find how to style the mathsiness and its been a while since i used LateX :O

Comment: What do you have to prove about $\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)\left(5^{k+2}-1  \right)$?

Comment: I have to get to that using the : i have so far line

Comment: By the way, here is a mathjax tutorial if you're interested :) http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks! I didn't check that one :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribute the factor $\frac 34$, and then factor out $5^{k+1}.\;$ Your expression is equivalent to:

$$5^{k+1}\left(\frac 34 + 3\right) - \frac 34 = \frac {15}{4}5^{k+1} - \frac 34= \frac 34(5\cdot 5^{k+1} - 1) = \frac 34(5^{k+2} - 1)$$

Comment: yep! thanks i just solved thanks to your help! much appreciated, im a bit rusty with exponentials :p

Comment: You're welcome!